# i am running a Computational DCEMRI/DWI with the implementation of R's dcemriS4 library using the following line of code as a refence:

Tags: arrays, image, github, windows-machine-learning

<kbd>TR <- 4.43 / 1000 # taken from CSV file dangle <- 25 # taken from CSV file  (fflip <- list.files(pattern="ax[0-9]"))  (fangles <- as.character(sub(".*ax([0-9]+).*", "\1", fflip)))  flip <- array(NA, c(dim(mask), length(fangles)))  for (fa in 1:length(fangles)) { flip[,,,fa] <- readNIfTI(fa) } `</kbd>

The error is ...
Error in strsplit(fname, "/") : non-character argument
when i run the last line of code i need help please`